# Where is my download list located ony htc desire?

Tags: htc-desire, download-manager

I used my Showbox app and tried to download something and it said "saved to download list"

Answer (score 0):

Open up your apps menu, and look for the "Downloads" app. That should bring up the "list" the message is referring to.